# Sms Gateway in spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sms

I have searched a lot but not able to found right code for sending sms to mobile from spring mvc java application. please help with some relevant links and example!
Thankyou

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Sms Gateway in spring mvc application？ Maybe you need to see how you can access the SMS gateway through the rest request. And give him  the parameter  he wants. Just HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

You need first to look for an SMS gateway that gives you free SMS quota then use spring mvc to send a rest request to this getaway to match their interface, some times you might need to call a URL with some parameter to send a message rather than a rest or xml message.

That's it.